# Android WebView error in showing Div

Tags: android, html, webview, android-webview

I'm  trying to display the div inside the WebView using the follwoing function

```
browser.loadData("<html> <head> <body> <H2> HI </H2>  " +
"<div id='map_canvas' style='width:20%;height:20%;'></div>" +
" </body> </head>  </html>", "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

but this doessn't load the html page gives the error

```
browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){
                System.out.println("URL:::"+url);
            }

            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                    System.out.println("URL:::"+failingUrl+" "+description+" "+errorCode);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        });
```

response shown as URL you are trying to load is invalid. please tell me what is wrong here

Comment: There is nothing wrong, what is api level ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android 2.3

```
    // display the data

    String baseUrl = "";
    String mimeType = "text/html";
    String encoding = "UTF-8";
    html = sb.toString();
    String historyUrl = "";

    webViewDataViewer.loadDataWithBaseURL(baseUrl, html, mimeType, encoding, historyUrl);
```

Comment: your function works but doesn't show the google-map of JavaScript code.screen comes as blank

Comment: in your question is nothing about google map, which probably need something else

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14213614/android-webview-loading-googlemap-data-rendering

Answer (score 0):

The % symbol does not load in Android 2.2 webview
It has to be encoded.